# How can I serialize JButton [ ]

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jbutton

I'm currently writing my school project in Java, in wich you have to manage the economy of a small village.
So the game looks like this: There is a Frame in which there are 49 SpecButtons (Explained later) representing the tiles of the village. Clicking on one opens a build menu from which you can choose what kind of building you want to build there etc....

I have created a new class which extends the JButton class and Implements Serializable called SpacButtons. To this class I added two integers, and a Buildings class type building variable (also a class I created) and some methods.

```
SpecButtons buttons=new SpecButtons[49];
```

So I have to save the game, using serialization, and this is how I tried to do that:

```
        private class SaveButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button) {
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("saves.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for(int x = 0;x<49;x++){
                oos.writeObject(buttons[x]);
            }
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("File Writing Error!");}

    }
}

private class LoadButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button) {

        try{
            FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream("saves.ser");
            ObjectInputStream oip = new ObjectInputStream(fip);
            for(int x=0;x<49;x++){
                buttons[x] = (SpecButtons) oip.readObject();
            }
            oip.close();
            fip.close();
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("File Reading Error!");}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){System.out.println("Class Not Found!");}
}
}
```

So, it creates the .ser file, but when I try to load it nothing happens.
If you guys have any idea how to make it work I would be quite grateful.

Comment: Does your file get created? When you load the buttons from the file, do these contain the right data (use the debugger to see if they are correctly deserialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, it creates the .ser file, but when I try to load it nothing happens.

Assuming your buttons are correctly de-serialized, you should add them to your main frame once loaded from the .ser file.

```
for(int x=0;x<49;x++){
  buttons[x] = (SpecButtons) oip.readObject();
}
// Add the buttons to the main frame where you would like them to appear...
```